# Try - Catch dentro de un Do - While (Java)

Tags: java, while, try-catch

He creado un código simple para realizar esta pregunta: ¿El Try - Catch funciona dentro de un bucle, en este caso un Do - While? Cada vez que se ejecuta el código y se escribe alguna letra, el bucle se detiene mostrando la excepción que se supone que el Catch debería controlar. Es una duda bastante grande que tengo, ya que utilizo varios bucles y me gustaría controlar las excepciones.

```
   **Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);
   
   Random random1 = new Random();
   Random random2 = new Random();
   Random random3 = new Random();
   
   boolean salirBucle = false;
   
   int valor1 = 0;
   int valor2 = 0;
   int valor3 = 0;
   int respuesta = 0;
   int suma = 0;
   
   System.out.println("SUMA ALEATORIA");
   System.out.println("Dos números aleatorios entre el 0 y 99 se sumarán");
   System.out.println("Se le mostrará uno de los dos");
   System.out.println("Tiene que adivinar la suma");
   
   do
   {
       valor1 = random1.nextInt(100);
       valor2 = random2.nextInt(100);
       valor3 = random3.nextInt(2) + 1;
       suma = valor1 + valor2;
       
       if(valor3 == 1)
       {
           System.out.println("El primer número es: " + valor1);
       }
       
       else if(valor3 == 2)
       {
           System.out.println("El segundo número es: " + valor2);
       }
       
       System.out.println("¿Cuál es la suma?");
       respuesta = entrada.nextInt();
           
       try
       {
           
           if(respuesta == suma)
           {
                System.out.println("¡CORRECTO!");
                System.out.println("El primer número era: " + valor1);
                System.out.println("El segundo número era: " + valor2);
                
                salirBucle = false;
           }
           
           else
           {
               System.out.println("¡INCORRECTO!");
           }
       }
       catch(java.util.InputMismatchException ex)
       {
           System.out.println("¡INCORRECTO!");       
       }
   }
   while(salirBucle == false);**
```

Comment: Bienvenido. Respuesta corta: si, el try catch funciona independientemente donde lo coloques. El problema debe ser otro. ¿Puedes dar un ejemplo de lo que ves que está mal y como debería verse? Mira como crear un [mre].

Comment: Según puedo ver así a la rápida el problema esta en la linea `respuesta = entrada.nextInt();` ya que mencionas que agregas una letra y el try no la controla, **esto es porque esa línea que te menciono no esta en el try y estas ingresando una letra cuando especificas que utilizarás enteros `entrada.nextInt()`**. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si vos recibes la entrada en el nextInt el try debe ir antes

```
try{
       System.out.println("¿Cuál es la suma?");
       respuesta = entrada.nextInt();
```

pero para evitar el loop debes limpiar el [buffer](https://www.clasesdeinformaticaweb.com/java-desde-cero/el-buffer-de-la-clase-scanner/) de la entrada

```
catch(java.util.InputMismatchException ex)
       {
           System.out.println("¡INCORRECTO!");  
           entrada.nextLine();  //limpiando el buffer   
       }
```